Why does the action handler function always capture the initial value of `useState`?
I have view where I want to add a scroll action listener to. I want to get the current scroll offset and compare its previous value to do something. Here is code:
const StickyBox = () => {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(500); // inital offset
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
    console.log(offset);  // always 500!
    setOffset(scrollY);    
    if (scrollY > offset) { ... }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => { window.removeEventListener(....); }
  }, []);

  return <div className="...">{offset}</div>
}

Now I know the right way to do this is to get the previous state in the useState parameter with a function.
setOffset((prev) => {
  if (scrollY > prev) {...}
})

But still I don't understand how JS closure work and how React useState work.
I can see that:

useEffect has a dependency of [] so it only invokes once. When I scroll the view, handleScroll gets called and setOffset gets called.
Since setOffset gets called, the component re-rendered, that is, the whole StickyBox function runs again, handleScroll function object is created again.

Q: 1. At this moment, handleScroll function just capture the offset variable, and the useState is expected to remember the value in its previous render, why console.log always output its initial value 500?

Since handleScroll is created on every render but useEffect just invokes once, does that mean, event listener just calls the initial handleScroll function over its lifecycle? Is such "function re-creation" considered to be good practice? Or because function object is ref type in heap, so each time the thing re-created is just a new stack variable that points to the same heap memory?


Define handleScroll within the effect hook callback function

You're not reassigning the event handler when the component re-renders and a new handleScroll is created. So it keeps calling the handleScroll function created in the initial render with a closure over the initial offset.
Add handleScroll to the effect's dependency array:
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => { window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll); }
}, [handleScroll]);

You may also change handleScroll to not require a closure on offset by passing a function to the state setter. That way it only needs to be created once:
const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
  const scrollY = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
  setOffset(previousOffset => {
    console.log(previousOffset);
    if (scrollY > previousOffset) { ... }
    return scrollY;
  });
}, []);

Note that memoization like useCallback is only an optimization and React does not guarantee that the function isn't recreated regardless, so you should still include the function in the effect's dependencies.
